# Java POST Connection Timeout Using HttpsUrlConnection

Tags: java, ajax, xml, http-post

I have a question about making a POST request with Java, and since this is my first attempt at something of this magnitude, please bear with me. I am working on a third party application in Java to connect to a website and make POST requests. Am I doing this correctly? Here is what I have so far:

Website Code:
(This is the code the website has for "bumping a trade" which simply sends 2 pieces of data to a php file. The URL is http://cdn.dota2lounge.com/script/trades.js)

```
function bumpTrade(trade, code) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/bumpTrade.php",
    data: "trade=" + trade + "&code=" + code
});
}
```

My Java Code:

```
private void sendPost() throws Exception {

        //String url = "https://www.cdn.dota2lounge.com/script/ajax/bumpTrade.php";
        String url = "https://www.cdn.dota2lounge.com/script/ajax/bumpTrade.php";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

//add request header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        String urlParameters = "trade=96510389&code=94cebd9";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        //print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());

    }
```

However I am receiving a connection timeout error when attempting to connect. I would be very grateful if someone could point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Java client code seems to be on the right track. But it looks like the URL in the code was the wrong URL.

Using the url "http://www.dota2lounge.com/ajax/bumpTrade.php" and HttpUrlConnection, I was able to get a 200 response (OK):

Sending 'POST' request to URL : http://www.dota2lounge.com/ajax/bumpTrade.php

Post parameters : trade=96510389&code=94cebd9

Response Code : 200

However nothing beyond that. Not sure of the API of the remote site but hopefully that's some help.

Comment: Yeah sorry, it just won't establish a connection. I can get the full error later but it can't connect. Am I putting in the wrong URL? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much man, I got a response too! I was using an HTTPS request vs HTTP which is why it refused to connect. Geese that is a relief.

Comment: @lsnow2017 Can you tell me how you fixed the issue, me too facing the same issue. If you could provide little more detail I can try it out, I have the same code as you had. Thanks.